# Sed uppercase lines if they starting with an uppercase character

Tags: sed

I want the lines starting with one uppercase character to be uppercased, other lines should be not touched.

So this input:

```
cat myfile
a
b
Cc
```

should result in this output:

```
a
b
CC
```

I tried this command, but this not matches if i use grouping:

`cat myfile | sed -r 's/\([A-Z]+.*\)/\U\1/g'`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are wrong: this works with `sed`:

`echo Hello | sed -r s/\(.*\)/\U\1/g`

But my regex not maches at all if i use grouping in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat myfile | sed 's/^\([A-Z].*\)$/\U\1/'
```

Answer (score 4):

When you use the `-r` option, you must not put `\` before parentheses used for grouping. So it should be:

```
sed -r 's/^([A-Z].*)/\U\1/' myfile
```

Also, notice that you need `^` to match the beginning of the line. The `g` modifier isn't needed, since you're matching the entire line.

Answer (score 1):

`\U` for uppercase conversion is a *GNU* `sed` extension.

Alternative for platforms where that is not available (e.g., macOS, with its *BSD* `awk` implementation):

```
awk '/^[A-Z]/ { print toupper($0); next } 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^[A-Z].*[a-z]/ s/.*/\U\1/' YourFile
```

only on line that are not compliant

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^[[:upper:]].*/\U&/' file
```